# Java split with special characters

Tags: java

I have below code that doing a split for string using `<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>` and it's not working using the special characters.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
          String str = "test<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>test"; 
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>", 2); 
        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            System.out.println(a);
     }
}
```

the output os `test<div>\$\$PZ\$\$</div>test`

it works when I remove the special characters

Can you please help.

Comment: `split` expects a regex. You need to escape those `$`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
String str = "test<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>test";
String[] arrOfStr = str.split("<div>\\\\\\$\\\\\\$PZ\\\\\\$\\\\\\$</div>", 2);
for (String a : arrOfStr) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

prints:

```
test
test
```

**EDIT**: Why do we need all those backslashes? It's because of how we need to handle String literals representing regex expressions. [This page](https://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-many-backslashes/198) describes the reason with examples. The essence is this:

For a backslash `\`...

...the *pattern* to match that would be `\\`... (to escape the escape)

... but the *string literal* to create that pattern would have to have one backslash to escape each of the two backslashes: `\\\\`.

Add to that the original need to also escape the `$`, that gives us our 6 backslashes in the string representation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you it's working, can you please explain your what did  you do exactly

Comment: He properly escaped all meta-characters. Backslashes are meta-characters in both the context of Java Strings and regular expressions so in order to match a literal backslash you want to write four backslashes (4 backslash in a Java String -> 2 backslash in regex -> one actual backslash matched), and `$` is a meta-character in the context of regular expressions so you need to prefix them with two backslashes ( `\\$` in Java String -> `\$` in regex -> one actual `$` matched)

Comment: Apologies for the solution without explanation. That was inappropriate.  I have edited my post.  Using @andreas's `Pattern.quote()` is new to me - that's a great solution.  Better than an unwieldy amount of backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, the parameter to [`split(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) is a *regular expression*, so some characters have special meaning. If you want the parameter to be treated *literally*, i.e. not as a regex, call the [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) method.

*Example*

```
String str = "test<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>test";
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(Pattern.quote("<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>"), 2);
for (String a : arrOfStr)
    System.out.println(a);
```

*Output*

```
test
test
```

The `quote()` method simply surrounds the literal text with the regex `\Q...\E` [quotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quot) pattern<sup>1</sup>, e.g. your `<div>\$\$PZ\$\$</div>` text becomes:

```regex
\Q<div>\$\$PZ\$\$</div>\E
```

For fixed text you could just do that yourself, i.e. the following 3 versions all create the same regex to split on:

```java
str.split(Pattern.quote("<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>"), 2)

str.split("\\Q<div>\\$\\$PZ\\$\\$</div>\\E", 2)

str.split("<div>\\\\\\$\\\\\\$PZ\\\\\\$\\\\\\$</div>", 2)
```

To me, the 3rd one, using `\` to escape, is the least readable/desirable version.

If there is a lot of special characters to escape, using `\Q...\E` is easier than `\`-escaping all the special characters separately, but very few people use it, so it's fairly unknown to most.

The `quote()` method is especially useful when you need to treat dynamic text literally, e.g. when the text to split on is configurable by the user.

<sup>*1) `quote()` will correctly handle literal text containing `\E`.*</sup>